# Redirect using PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

Hi i am trying to create a PHP script to redirect people from an old shop to a new shop.

If users land on a product page the url will look like this:

```
www.example.com/cart/product-name-p-xxxx.html
```

`p-xxxx.html` is on the end of all product name URLs, it is just a product id number (which is always 4 digits) which is no longer used. I need to re-write the URL to:

```
www.example.com/shop/?s=product%20name&post_type=product
```

I was planning to place the script on the root of `www.example.com/cart/` to pick up all requests to the old shop. (There are over 2000 product pages, so I can't write individual redirects for each product.)

I have no idea where to start on this, so any help, pointers and/or examples would be great.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't have to be a PHP script, it can use any form of technology if the results are the same.

Comment: Look up mod_rewrite. You're going to need to make a RewriteRule in your .htaccess file to do this.

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? (I'm assuming Apache?) How important is the substitution of hyphens with spaces (`%20`) in the URL. Spaces in the URL are always best avoided, particularly for a (new) shop.

Comment: Does the "product-name" always consist of 2 words? (TBH, I did not consider this when I first read the question, however, the current answer does assume this and this certainly does make it easier if choosing to go the server config / .htaccess route?)

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you could have something like this:

```
$array = array();
preg_match("/\/(.\*?)-(.\*?)-p-(.\*?)\./", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $array);

header("Location: www.example.com/shop/?s=" . $array[1] . "%20" . $array[2] . "&post_type=product", true, 302);
```